# jQuery's show animation

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to invert the `show('slow')` animation on jQuery? I want it to look like it is going backwards.

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried [jQuery's hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method ...  `.hide('slow')` ?

Comment: Oh, it was that easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).  Or just use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for a complete list

Answer (score 1):

You can try hide with slow parameter

```
hide.('slow');
```